# error subir img con intervection POO php

Tags: php, mysql, poo

actualmente mientras estoy haciendo un curso de desarrollo web estoy atascado en unas lineas de codigo de subida de imagen hacia la base de datos.

$nombreImagen = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)) . ".jpg";

```
        realiza un resize con intervection a la imagen
        if($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']) {
           $Image = $imagen::make($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'])->fit(800,600);
           $propiedad->setImagen($nombreImagen);
        }
        
    //validar
    $errores = $propiedad->validar();
        
    if(empty($errores)) {

        

        crear la caprta imagenes
        if(!is_dir(CARPETAS_IMAGENES)){
            mkdir(CARPETAS_IMAGENES);
        }

        guardar imagen
        $Image->save(CARPETAS_IMAGENES . $nombreImagen);
```

el error que salta es el siguiente

Warning: Undefined variable $imagen in D:\Downloads\CURSO DESARROLLO WEB\Desarrollo Web\bienesraices\bienesraices\admin\propiedades\crear.php on line 41

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in D:\Downloads\CURSO DESARROLLO WEB\Desarrollo Web\bienesraices\bienesraices\admin\propiedades\crear.php:41 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\Downloads\CURSO DESARROLLO WEB\Desarrollo Web\bienesraices\bienesraices\admin\propiedades\crear.php on line 41

Comment: Fácil no existe la clase $imagen, no la has definido. ¿No será Image::make en lugar de $imagen::make?

Comment: he probado varias opciones y ambas me salen como que la clase no esta definida y si que las tengo en otro archivo php

if(!$this->imagen){
           self::$errores[] = 'debes añadir una imagen';
        }

Comment: Pues no habrás importado el archivo con esa clase definida.